# Name 'model' is not defined

Tags: python, model, regression

When I input this code

```
print(cross_val_score(model, X, y, cv=3))
```

An error comes back that reads `name 'model' is not defined`:

```
print(cross_val_score(model, X, y, cv=3))

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/b7/ltdcsdbx0ds1pftc_qmt_k900000gn/T/ipykernel_32984/4204694188.py in <module>
----> 1 print(cross_val_score(model, X, y, cv=3))

NameError: name 'model' is not defined
```

Comment: Did you run the code cell creating `model` before running this?

Comment: I figured it out I had to go further back and create a model and associate it with a regression model

Answer (score 1):

If you're running your code cell-by-cell in an editor like Jupyter, you'll need to make sure that you **run all the cells needed to define each element** that you will be using in the line that you are trying to run.

Comment: This is also pointed out by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72241417/name-model-is-not-defined/72241513#comment127633339_72241417) comment by @monk.